# twitter card image from external website

Tags: image, twitter

I have a twitter share button on a webpage. I have submitted my website for twitter cards, and it is approved. I am using the twitter card tags correctly, but I have troubles to get the images appear on the time-line. On the twitter timeline I only see text and the URL. Only when clicking on the tweet, an image appears below (the tweet expands).

I would like to have this image appear on the timeline, without needing to expand the tweet. Is this possible, or am is it necessary to use a service like twitpic or flickr to make this happen?

My first thought is that this is not possible because twitter only accepts certain image websites to publish their images on the twitter timeline, but I cannot find a twitter dev source that confirms this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour for the twitter card.
Please read https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting#timeline

The second point of the troubleshooting might be the solution you're looking for: "For photos and animated GIFs, upload the media directly with the Tweet or consider using the Twitter API to upload media." You can also explore the other solutions offered.

UPDATE: It looks like the solution I was proposing refers to sharing content directly from twitter, so it's not an option. See this [twitter community thread](https://twittercommunity.com/t/galley-card-not-appearing-in-timeline/37187)